# Laravel: Como recuperar último registro inserido no banco mysql pela sua chave estrangeira?

Tags: laravel

Estou trabalhando em uma banco de dados que possui somente como referencia a sua chave estrangeira, e preciso localizar o ultimo registro em função de sua chave estrangeira.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se tiver os campos timestamp padrões do laravel, vc pode dar um

```
SuaClasse::where('chave_estrangeira', $chave)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
```

Senão uma opção seria dar o orderBy pelo ID da mesma forma, comparando a chave estrangeira

Comment: Muito obrigada Ademilson Santana da Silva salvou meu dia!